# Autoadjusted height to always show content

Tags: css

This snippet is part of a more complex mobile layout. The only thing I cannot edit is the `section` height and overflow.

The structure is simple: 2 divs, the first one contains an image, the latter textual content. I'm trying to make the textual content (inside the red border) always visible and not cropped out of the page, no matter the device resolution or the device orientation (landscape/portrait). Currently is cropped out of the page on landscape or very low resolution. When the textual content doesn't have enough space, the `div.logo` have to be reduced in height.

```html
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0
  }
  
  section {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100vh;
    /*cannot edit*/
    overflow: hidden/*cannot edit*/
  }
  
  div {
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  div.logo img {
    height: 100%
  }
  
  div.logo {
    height: 40vh
  }
  
  div.content {
    background: lightgreen;
  }
  
  span {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block
  }
</style>
<section>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span>this content should be always visible, div.logo should be resized in height in case of div.content doesn't have enough space
        <br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>
     <button>button 1</button><button>button 2</button>
     </span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here the current state and what I want to accomplish

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You may to fix the height of any content automatly, if you use the image logo as a background, it would be better because the css code resize the height using the following propenty:

```
 -webkit-background-size: cover;        /* Safari 3.0 */
 -moz-background-size: cover;           /* Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6) */
   -o-background-size: cover;           /* Opera 9.5 */
      background-size: cover;           /* Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4.0) and other CSS3-compliant browsers */
```

If you need to use the background in DOM you can use this style on line:

```
 <tagname style=background-image:(url);"> </tagname>
```

I hope it works, let me know if you need something else.

Comment: I don't get how `background-size:cover` could solve, maybe I was not so clear. The height of the `div.logo` (or the image, it doesn't matter) should reduce its height to make ALL below the content visible.
But maybe `backgroud-size:contain` could be a way..